# C++: How to build relationships between srtucts by this way?

Tags: c++, relationship

I am a beginner with c+, I working on a project: "Educational Management System" I found difficult and struggle when I came to part to code relationships between objects and the way of they will access each other, so this is my approach:

```
struct doctor
{
    person info;
    vector <course> courses;
};

struct student
{
    person info;
    vector <course> courses;
    vector <assignmentSolution> assignmentSolutions;
};

struct course
{
    int code;
    string title;
    doctor lecturer;
    vector <student> registeredStudents;
    vector <assignment> assignments;
};


vector <doctor> doctors;
vector <student> students;
vector <course> courses;
```

So doctors will created course by:

```
courses.push_back(newCourse);
doctors[index].courses.push_back(newCourse);
```

This is wrong but I wonder how to create it only once in memmory but keep in mind student will register in courses after that.

Comment: Let the member vectors store the index of each course/assignment/student.

Comment: @ViktorSehr wouldn't this lead to problems, when a course is deleted?

Comment: I think @ViktorSehr approach is good. But you should have a good mapping from id to doctor, maybe using `std::map` or a `std::vector<std::pair<ID,doctor>>`. This way you can delete a doctor without invalidating all ids.

Comment: (Re-)read the pointers chapter in your textbook and also check `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: When you go to check `std::shared_ptr`, then also check `std::weak_ptr`, since you might build a loop with your shared pointers.

Comment: why use shared_ptr in the first place, there should only be a school struct that owns the courses, so unique_ptr, and the others get a raw ptr

Comment: @Yamahari, so the `school::deleteCourse` would be responsible to inform all doctors and student structs to remove this course from their courses list?

Comment: well each course has a list of attending students, so that could be a way

Comment: problem is, the courses don't know about the doctors: make a base class SchoolMember, that has the stuff doctor has, and make student extend it with solutions vector

Comment: The course knows the `doctor lecturer`.

Comment: ah yes, i am blind apparently. Hm well then the question is do the student need to access the course struct even, or only know the name or smth.

Answer (score 1):

Might have went a little overboard, but using the visitor pattern you can make the course system extensibly:
Basically you have a school class that owns the courses. There school members can register through calling registerMember(code, member). The courses themself don't own the school members, only pointers to them

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Course;
struct School;

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  int age;
};

struct SchoolMember {
  Person info;  // composition unless person has functionality that SchoolMember
                // needs
  std::vector<Course*> courses;  // maybe map for easier deletion
  School* school;

  virtual ~SchoolMember() {}
  virtual void visit(Course* course) = 0;
};

struct Student;
struct Doctor;

struct Course {
  int code;
  std::string title;
  Doctor* mainDoctor;
  std::vector<Student*> students;

  virtual ~Course() {}

  virtual void accept(Student* student) = 0;
  virtual void accept(Doctor* doctor) = 0;

  virtual void cleanUp() {
    // remove me from student'S lists etc.
  }
};

struct Student final : SchoolMember {
  void visit(Course* course) override {
    courses.emplace_back(course);
    course->accept(this);
    // additional stuff
  }
};

struct Doctor final : SchoolMember {
  void visit(Course* course) override {
    courses.emplace_back(course);
    course->accept(this);
    // additional stuff
  }
};

struct Course101 final : Course {
  void accept(Student* student) {
    // Reject advanced students, etc.
    students.emplace_back(student);
  }
  void accept(Doctor* doctor) {
    // Replace current doctor
  }
};

struct CourseAdvanced final : Course {
  Doctor* secondaryDoctor;

  void accept(Student* student) {
    // Reject 101 students, etc.
    students.emplace_back(student);
  }
  void accept(Doctor* doctor) {
    // I can have multiple doctors!

  }
};

struct School {
  std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Course>> courses; // School owns the courses

  void addCourse(int code /**/) {
    // create new course
  }

  void registerMember(int code, SchoolMember* member) {
    if(auto it = courses.find(code); it != courses.end()) {
      member->visit(it->second.get());
    }
  }

  void removeCourse(int code) {
    if(auto it = courses.find(code); it != courses.end()) {
      it->second->cleanUp();
      courses.erase(it);
    }
  }
};
```